# Using the wordpress plugin, how do I overide the the template files, ie EventInfo.tpl?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have spend a number of hours trying to figure this out.  If I want to change one of the template files, say EventInfo.tpl, but not inside the plugin so updates would not override it.  How do I need to do that?

Comment: @ramesh, Thank you for your answer.  I want to just create a custom template folder.  I have read that linked content many times.  Every time I go set the custom template directory, I get a 'Custom Templates' directory does not exist error, event though the folder does exist.

Comment: Can you share with us the directory where you placed your 'custom-templates' folder and what you've typed in the field for "Custom Templates" in the Directories screen?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to over ride a .tpl you can just do that by creating an extension or by using custom template folder in civicrm

which will be more easier - also, in the time of upgrade you need to compare the file and do the changes

More reading:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in,+Profile,+Contribution+and+Event+Registration+Screens

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension

I guess this helps !!!